# advantage of using Stash with LVs or Low Variables by itself

Tags: stash, low-variables

Can someone comment on if there is an advantage over Option 1 vs Option 2 or vice-versa.

```
Option 1 - Stash with LVs

{exp:stash:set name="product_description"}
{if segment_3 == 'content-management'}{lv_cm}{/if}
{if segment_3 == 'crm'}{lv_crm}{/if}
{if segment_3 == 'project-management'}{lv_pjm}{/if}
{if segment_3 == 'business-intelligence'}{lv_bi}{/if}
{if segment_3 == 'marketing-automation'}{lv_ma}{/if}
{/exp:stash:set}  

{exp:stash:parse}   
<p>{stash:product_description}</p>
{/exp:stash:parse}

Option 2 - Low Variables only

{if segment_3 == 'content-management'}{lv_cm}{/if}
{if segment_3 == 'crm'}{lv_crm}{/if}
{if segment_3 == 'project-management'}{lv_pjm}{/if}
{if segment_3 == 'business-intelligence'}{lv_bi}{/if}
{if segment_3 == 'marketing-automation'}{lv_ma}{/if}
```

Any advice is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

There'll be a slight hit to the stash version but if used correctly it can be utilized to cache the results.

So there's plus & minus to both versions.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of using Stash here is for markup reusability. In your example you've wrapped a simple `<p>` tag around your `product_description` variable... In real world use on a large site, that markup might be 50 lines long and be reused in a dozen different templates. Stash allows you to abstract that markup away so that you only need to update it once. In the pure LV approach, you'd need to repeat that markup 5 times.